# Remove tags from IconStyle

Tags: java, kml, jak

I'm using the Java API for KML(JAK) to write some KML.  Basically, I have a route and at each vertex of the route is a waypoint.  Each waypoint has the potential for having a different icon image, so the desired KML looks something like this:

```
<Placemark>
    <description>Hello World!</description>
    <Style>
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>image2.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>0,1,2</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Instead, I get something like this:

```
<Placemark>
<description>Hello World!</description>
    <Style>
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>0.0</scale>
            <heading>0.0</heading>
            <Icon>
                <href>image2.png</href>
                <refreshInterval>0.0</refreshInterval>
                <viewRefreshTime>0.0</viewRefreshTime>
                <viewBoundScale>0.0</viewBoundScale>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>0,1,2</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

I'm trying to understand what is forcing tags like `<scale>` and `<refreshInterval>` to be in the KML that I am writing(if I haven't specified scale, I don't want the tag in there at all).  The `.xsd` that JAK is built on shows that minOccurs = 0 for these elements, and I've tried explicitly setting the values to `-1.0` and setting the `@XmlElement(required = false)`, though I'm completely new to all of this so I'm not even sure that has an affect on writing xml or just reading it.

I should add that I haven't changed the `.xsd` files yet, so here's the relevant part that helped generate code:

```
<element name="IconStyle" type="kml:IconStyleType" substitutionGroup="kml:AbstractColorStyleGroup" />
<complexType name="IconStyleType" final="#all">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="kml:AbstractColorStyleType">
            <sequence>
                <element ref="kml:scale" minOccurs="0" />
                <element ref="kml:heading" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="Icon" type="kml:BasicLinkType" minOccurs="0" />
                <element ref="kml:hotSpot" minOccurs="0" />
                <element ref="kml:IconStyleSimpleExtensionGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <element ref="kml:IconStyleObjectExtensionGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Any ideas on what I need to change to make it so these tags aren't included with 0.0s?  If I end up going too in-depth then I might as well write the KML myself, but I've found the JAK library to be very useful so far.